# How to submit data to mysql using jquery selectable

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, jquery-ui

I have a code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tcuapb16/2/.

I want that when i click submit, it sends the value of the images selected to my php file where it inserts the data in my database. But i don't know really how to connect it to the php.

PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php  
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db2");
@include_once('set.php');   
if(!isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {  //if is not logged, return to main page
    Header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
$itemid = // value from images selected  
$id = $_SESSION["userid"];  
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE users SET `itemid`='$itemid' WHERE `userid`='$id'");  
Header("Location: index.php");  
exit;  
?>
```

Comment: You should give just enough of the jquery alongside the jfiddle link to give a sense of the problem.